# No DNS AAAA response from Fortigate

Tags: dns, ipv6, fortigate

I've tried to setup IPv6 only home lan, but DNS seems to not work as expected. To enable NAT64 I had to change public DNS servers to my firewall (which is preffered option anyway). I'm using Fortigate with latest firmware 7.4

It successfully resolves A records:

```
nslookup -type=A ip4only.me 
Server:     2001:xxxx:xxxx:4c03::f
Address:    2001:xxxx:xxxx:4c03::f#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ip4only.me
Address: 23.153.8.78
```

as well as translate IPv4 to IPv6 responses

```
nslookup -type=AAAA ip4only.me
Server:     2001:xxxx:xxxx:4c03::f
Address:    2001:xxxx:xxxx:4c03::f#53

Non-authoritative answer:
ip4only.me  has AAAA address 64:ff9b::1799:84e
```

The issue is with IPv6 only sites where Fortigate doesn't reply:

```
nslookup -type=AAAA ip6only.me                     
Server:     2001:xxxx:xxxx:4c03::f
Address:    2001:xxxx:xxxx:4c03::f#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find ip6only.me: No answer
```

Of course public DNS servers can resolve this query:

```
nslookup -type=AAAA ip6only.me 2001:4860:4860::8888
Server:     2001:4860:4860::8888
Address:    2001:4860:4860::8888#53

Non-authoritative answer:
ip6only.me  has AAAA address 2001:4810:0:3::78
```